# Is it possible to start a Activity as a new process

Tags: android, process

I have this situation where i have to start an activity from my mainActivity. But I want this new activity to be started as a new process(With new process ID). Is it possible to achieve this in android. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "But I want this new activity to be started as a new process(With new process ID)." -- why? I can think of no good reason for this. AFAICT, all you will do is waste RAM, waste CPU, and waste battery for no benefit.

Comment: In order to overload the system by starting new processes over and over ... there's a well known bug that will get you root access once the PID limit is reached and ADB tries to restart.  As it boots it does so in super user mode.  After it gets done with it's activities it tries to set its permissions down to be a regular user but since the PID cap has been reached that process fails.  You're left with shell access and root.  That'd be my guess for why he wants it ;)

Comment: I don't know why the OP wants it, but I have a use case: I want to start and then shut down a third-party library that I know does not clean up after itself (it cannot be safely restarted inside the same process). Being able to start a new process with a new JVM and new instances of native libraries can be important.

Comment: Aside from the fact that the above comments are ignorant, its not up to you as to why somebody wants a particular piece of code.

There are many applications which could use a separate application container. For example, if you have a webserver running in the same process space as your activities, and the server crashes, you cannot provide any instrumentation and you will likely lose key context information about the crash itself, depending on how you log your data.

Being able to spawn off a seperate process for code that might crash is a must have feature. Despite what ignorance may say.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just put **android:process=":ProcessName"** for your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
     android:name=".YourActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:process=":YourProcessName">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In this case "YourActivity" will be run on other process called "YourProcessName".

Comment: Can u give a little more explanation on that. I am not aware of it.

Comment: it will simply set a new process for the activity , which will be different from the other one you used before . this way , you can have a process1 for activity1 and process2 for activity2 .

Comment: @AndroSelva I have the main activity running. Is it possible to start the same activity as a another process?